# Recuperar array json ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

estoy tratando de recuperar los valores que paso por un array en json a ajax.

este es el codigo que uso:

```
function CompletarEan(cod) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "./Scripts/Phps/Autocompletar.php?pag=autocompletar_Ean&term="+cod,
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#InAlbaran_Articulo").val(data.idean);
            $("#InAlbaran_Ean").val('');
            console.log(data.idean);

},
error: function(xhr, status, error){ $().toastmessage('showToast', { text : 'Error con ean '+ xhr.responseText, sticky : true, type : 'error' }); }
    });
}
```

y este es el array que me devuelve json:

```
[{"idean":"1316","nombre":"843446300058"}]
```

el caso es que quisiera asignar esos valores recibidos a distintos input pero no se porque me da como resultado undefinied.

¿que puedo estar haciendo mal? o ¿como se recuperan los valores en ajax?

Comment: Usa **console.log(data);** para ver que estructura estas recibiendo; por lo que pones es un array debe ser **data[0].idean**.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas según la consola data recibe: [{idean: "1316", nombre: "843446300058"}] que es lo mismo que muestra el navegador al entrar a la pagina directa

Comment: Eso era XD me faltaba el [0] ¿me lo pones como respuesta oficial que te de por resuelto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Saludos**

El dato que recibes es un array; bastara con que indiques el índice que deseas acceder; si es un único elemento:

```
$("#InAlbaran_Articulo").val(data[0].idean);
```

Answer (score 6):

> y este es el array que me devuelve json: 
>   [{"idean":"1316","nombre":"843446300058"}]

si te regresa el resultado de esa manera encerrado dentro de `[...]` significa que es un array en este caso tienes un array de objetos dentro de un array asi que creo que podrias, primero obtener la posicion del array y luego los objetos que contenga

aqui un ejemplo :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var conten = [{"idean":"1316","nombre":"843446300058"}];
  alert(conten[0].idean);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilizando [JsonEditorOnline](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=7a4c602bc265480fa4a53f7a6985c8eb) se ve así el Json:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que debes acceder de la siguiente manera:

```
...
success: function(data) {
        $("#InAlbaran_Articulo").val(data[0].idean);
        $("#InAlbaran_Ean").val('');
        console.log(data[0].idean);
...
```